# How to get all markers from SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want to add markers from a SQLite db to maps.
I want the markers show when maps starting (in onMapReady()).
I have a code for my SQLite database inilizetion, and loading db from the Asset folder

SQLHelper.java

```
public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "atm-terdekat.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.mm.atmterdekat/databases/";
    private Context myContext;

    public SQLHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        myContext=context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        if(DataBaseisExist()){
            //do nothing - database already exist
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "Database Sudah Ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
            //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
                Toast.makeText(myContext, "Database Berhasil Diimport Dari Assets", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

    }

    private boolean DataBaseisExist(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){
            //database does't exist yet.
        }
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        if(checkDB != null )return true ;else return false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And this is my maps Fragment. This where I want my markers starting in onMapReady().

BNIFragment.java

```
public class BNIMapsFragment extends Fragment  implements OnMapReadyCallback{

    // DB
    SQLHelper dbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;

    //    vars
    private GoogleMap mMap;



    public BNIMapsFragment() {

    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootVIew = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bnimaps, container, false);

        // membuat DB
        dbHelper = new SQLHelper(this.getActivity());
        try {
            dbHelper.createDataBase();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Query untuk menampilkan semua Mall
        final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM atm_bni", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();


        // what's next ?

        return rootVIew;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.bnimaps);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
//        mMap = googleMap;
//
//        LatLng ll = new LatLng(-7.76303354, 110.39192754);
//
//        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
//        options.position(ll).title("Universitas Mercu Buana Yogyakarta");
//        mMap.addMarker(options);
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 15f));


    }

}
```

UPDATE:

atm_bni table:

[image]

Comment: Instead of saving markers to database, Store latitude and longitude and at the time of loading map, fetch list of all lat, long and for each latitude, longitude show marker on map.

Comment: You should post the atm_bni table structure in order to answer your question. What's your "marker model" like?

Comment: opps sorry. I just updated my post. now you can see atm_bni table. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, just a customized the part with querying the database results:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    // membuat DB
    dbHelper = new SQLHelper(this.getActivity());
    try {
        dbHelper.createDataBase();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    // Query untuk menampilkan semua Mall
    final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM atm_bni", null);
    final LatLngBounds.Builder mapBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    boolean addedMarker = false;
    if (cursor != null) {
        while (cw.moveToNext()) {
            double latitude = cursor.getDouble("latitude");
            double longitude = cursor.getDouble("longitude");

            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latitude, longitude)
                .anchor(0.5F, 1.0F)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
            mapBuilder.include(marker.getPosition());
            addedMarker = true;
        }
        if (!cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
            cursor = null;
        }
    }

    if (addedMarker) {
        final LatLngBounds mapBounds = mapBuilder.build();
        final CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mapBounds, 0);
        googleMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }
}
```

Comment: it works. thanks.and how to ad moveCamera around those markers?

Comment: I got error "java.lang.NullPointerException". how to fix it?